# can't view the result of a query that i returned with json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my method in the controller that gets the product id and returning the supllier using json:

```
public ActionResult GetProductData(int ProductId)
            {
                var data = from m in db.Products
                      join sa in db.SupPro on m.ProductID equals sa.ProductID
                      join f in db.Supplier on sa.CompanyID equals f.CompanyID
                      where m.ProductID == ProductId
                      select new { CompanyName = f.NameS, AdressCompany = f.Address, PhoneCompany = f.Phone };
                return Json(new { foo = data.ToList(), ball = "dragon", elementId = ProductId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

the output on screen was: data res :[object Object] dragon 4

those are my model classes:

the customer model:

```
 public class Customer

{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public String NameS { get; set; }
    public String NameP { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Phone { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SupPro> SupPro { get; set; }
}
```

the supplier class:

```
   public class Supplier
        {
            [Key]
            public int CompanyID { get; set; }
            public String NameS { get; set; }
            public String Address { get; set; }
            public String Phone { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<SupPro> SupPro { get; set; }
        }
```

the product class:

```
public class Products
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public String NameP { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SupPro> SupPro { get; set; }
    }
```

and the supPro class:

```
public class SupPro
    {
        [Key]
        public int SupProID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public DateTime SupplyDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Products Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

can someone tell me what is my problem so i will be able to view the result from the query as i want.

thanks.

Comment: this can be help you http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

Comment: Show you client side code!

Comment: You cannot directly `print` the json data to browser. You need to iterate the json object and consume individual properties. Or else you need to use some kind of binding libraries like `knockout.js` to handle client side json binding with html for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your json will be accessible in a jQuery `success` or `done` call as follows:

foo is a collection so it will be accessible via indexing or a loop, then the property name.

As an example to get the first `CompanyName` property.

```
data.foo[0].CompanyName
```

More commonly you would use a loop to output these with jQuery you can use `$.each` and append them to an element.

The other elements you define will be accessible via:

```
data.ball
data.elementId
```

**Update**

```
 success: function (data) {
                            var x = data;

                            $.each(data.foo, function (i, item) {
                               $nextElm.append(item.CompanyName + '<br/>');
                            });

                         }
```

Obviously change the append to your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll help, but if you have a JavaScript variable containing a JSON class or array, and if you are using AngularJS, then it's really easy to display the value in a readable form:

```
<pre> {{ myArrayOfObjects | json }} </pre>
```

I use this trick a lot, particularly when writing AngularJS code, and testing that my controls are binding to the correct fields within a JSON object.

[image]

But yes, you're right, without AngularJS, trying to display the contents of such a variable will just return a pointless:

```
[object Object]
```